# Display and Hide PNG image in Tkinter Python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Like the topic, 
how can I display a `.png` image and hide it? And what is the difference between *canvas* and *photoimage*?

Comment: What have you tried to display a .png image? At what point it failed? Please edit in your code and add error etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a bit of code which hides/shows an image on the click of a button. You can edit it to fit your needs.

NOTE: At the moment, I'm using `pack()`, and `pack_forget()`, if you want to use grid or place, you must use `grid_forget()` or `place_forget()`

import tkinter

```
def hideBG():
    global state
    if state == "Hidden":
        background_label.pack()
        state = "Showing"

    elif state == "Showing":
        background_label.pack_forget()
        state = "Hidden"




window = tkinter.Tk()

background_image=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="BG.png")
background_label = tkinter.Label(window, image=background_image)

hideBttn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Hide Background", command=hideBG)
state = "Showing"

hideBttn.pack()
background_label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

This creates an image within a label, and a button. The button takes the current "state" of the image (whether it is hidden or showing), and changes it to the opposite, by calling the hideBG function when the button is pressed.

Hope this helps!